# Bitcoin Core not updating to latest block

Tags: core, bitcoin

I have Bitcoin Core 24.0.1 64bit on Windows 10 which is seemingly stuck on updating with the latest transactions. It seems also that I have port 8333 blocked (checked on https://canyouseeme.org/), but not sure if that's even relevant. I am receiving "outbound" traffic in the peers-view window. I tried chaging the port to 8332, 80 and other random ports in the bitcoin.conf file but to no avail. I also tried deleting the peers.dat file but also without any impact. This used to work last year, I would appreciate any info on how I can get this updated so I can transfer by BTC.

[seeking peers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEztj.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ is probably where you should be asking